# Service Worker error on chrome mobile webview : TypeError · Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

```
TypeError · Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://example.com/') with script ('https://example.com/sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

I have a react app where service worker registeration is working fine on chrome.
But it is giving issue on mobile webview (got this information through error logs).
I tried looking for a solution on internet but could not get any hint as to where and why the error is occurring.

This is how my service worker file looks like:
**serviceWorker.js**

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.


function startRegistering(config) {
  try {
    const swUrl = `${window.location.origin}/sw.js`;
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(function(registration) {
          registration.update();
          if (config.onRegistered) {
            config.onRegistered();
          }
          
          if (config.onMessagingActivated) {
            config.onMessagingActivated();
          }
          console.log(
            'Service worker registered'
          );
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // Failed registration, service worker won’t be installed
          console.log(
            `Service worker registration failed, error:`,
            err
          );
        })
    );

    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then( registrations => {
        for (const registration of registrations) {
          if (registration.active !== null) {
            if (registration.active.scriptURL !== swUrl) {
              registration.unregister();
            }
          }
        }
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      `Something went wrong in service worker registration, error:${error}`
    );
  }
}

export function register(config = {}) {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      startRegistering(config);
    });
  }
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

When I checked the breadcrumb of error log, it shows the message for successful service worker registeration.

Any guidance would be great.